# Vue2: Init data with other data value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to initialize a username input with the value of an email if the username is not set/empty upfront. In the code below, I just get an `[object HTMLInputElement]` inside the username input but it should be the email address.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" v-model="email">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" v-model="username">
```

Vue

```
var username = '';

var App = window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      username: username ? username : email,
}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues here is your `input` element has the `id="username"`. In browsers, HTML elements are exposed as global variables with the id as the name of the variable, so you are defining *two* global variables with the name `username`.

Change one of them.

Secondly you never define the value of `email` in this statement:

```
username ? username : email
```

You define the value of the `email` *property* on the `data` object, but `data.email !== email`. `email` is actually the `input` element with the `id="email"`. Instead try this.

```
var currentUsername = '';

var App = window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      username: null
    },
    created(){
       this.username = currentUsername || this.email
    }
})
```

```js
console.clear()

var currentUsername = '';

var App = window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      username: null
    },
    created(){
       this.username = currentUsername || this.email
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" v-model="email">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" v-model="username">
</div>
```

**Update**

I wanted to clarify a bit for future readers. I've left the original answer above.

DOM elements with an `id` property [are exposed on the `window` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) in all major browsers.

So in defining these two input elements in the OP's question

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" v-model="email">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" v-model="username">
```

There are now two variables on the `window` object with the names `username` and `email`.

In OP's code, he defined a variable called `username` and set it to an empty string.

```
var username = '';
```

This variable *overrides* the variable created by the input element having the `id` of `username` because it is declared with a `var`. However there is nothing that overrides the `email` variable on the window. So when the code tries to set the default value of the `username` property of data object,

```
username: username ? username : email,
```

`username` resolves to an empty string, which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), and the default value for the `username` property is set to the value of the `email` global variable, which is a reference to the input element with the `id="email"`.

This is why the OP's code was showing the textbox with `[object HTMLInputElement]` inside as the value.

Comment: so, you are saying that window.username is a html element? it doesn't make much sense your answer

Comment: @John That is exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: i legit didn't know this after all these years

Comment: If i change the input id to something other than `username` it's still not working.

Comment: username: username ? username : email ... email variable does not exist

Comment: @john thats true too, just noticed

Comment: username: currentUsername || email . shorter :P .. or you could set the this.username in the created() or mounted() with this.email not just email

Comment: @BertEvans The username input should not be initialized with a global var but with the vue email data

Comment: It only worked after doing the init inside the created(). Why is that needed? Why not directly inside the data definition?

Comment: Because `email` is not defined. You set `data` to a an object with a property of `email` but `email` in your ternary was not the same thing.